Can laws operate in an immaterial universe?
Suppose you have a world that is completely immaterial, perhaps a solipsistic universe if there is only one conscious experience (related to you), or the internal workings of god's mind, or the end product of a simulation but without any hardware to simulate on.
Now, in this world, can you still have objects that move around in an orderly fashion? Of course, every example we've ever come across in regards to laws does involve some sort of "hardware". When it comes to video games, the hardware is the computer chips that the computer program "operates on". When it comes to our minds and generating our conscious experience, the hardware is our brain. When it comes to the entire universe, the "hardware" is the world itself: concrete objects that exist in the world that the laws of the universe "operate" on. Note that I use the word operate in quotes because whether or not laws are merely descriptions about the world or are prescriptive, they still "work with" hardware.
Now, can laws operate on a purely immaterial world where there are no concrete objects, and all objects are mere images or abstractions of some sort. Is there anything incoherent about this? If not incoherent, is there anything implausible about this?
EDIT:
Note that by immaterial, I am ultimately referring to a conscious world, not a mathematically platonic sort of world.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Consider the world of a cellular automaton such as Conway's Game of Life, started from some random input state. If you are willing to adopt a meta-mathematical realist (Platonist) stance, then this world is as real as real can be, independent from any mind. Being a purely abstract world, it is immaterial. Yet the dynamics of all events and changes in that immaterial world are governed by a tiny set of laws -- general rules -- that describe how cells may change state from one discrete time step to another, depending on their own state and the states of other cells in their neighborhood.
So, in that sense, laws -- general rules of how states in a world are updated with the passage of time -- can operate in an "immaterial world".
If this is not what you meant by an "immaterial world", then I've no idea what you would consider as such, or what meaning the question about laws could have.
UPDATE
If we don't consider a Platonic world - but a world of conscious experience, and assume that that could exist independently from any material world, as dualist Cartesians used to do, then it's also perfectly possible and conceivable that transitions in this world -- changes of one complete conscious state into another or partial changes in aspects of a conscious state - are ruled by certain laws. A law as such is not more than a repeatable pattern or a repeatedly observed relation. Spinoza in his Ethics was one of the first who actually tried to describe and explain, in detail, conscious experience in these terms.
But we don't have to assume that consciousness experience is independent of a material substrate in order to discover laws that govern different states or that explain transitions. Whether conscious experience is always carried by physical processes or not, is irrelevant for finding specific laws about conscious processes. Spinoza's theory of the emotions has, for instance, strongly influenced some contemporary psychology of emotion. See, for instance, Nico Frijda's The Emotions, or The Laws of Emotion. Computational theories of (aspects) of conscious cognition and perception also as such do not need to presuppose any specific physical processes (or laws of physics).

Yes but how “real” is that world? Actually seeing that game occur with all the different changed states always occurs with some material hardware involved. In our imagination, that hardware is from our brain. In the case of simulating this game on a computer, the hardware are the circuits. Can this world be real without a material substrate?

How "real" are sets of numbers? What is meant by calling them "real" (or by negating that)? Surely, I can make true statements about a given set? Isn't that enough to make them "real"?

Well the response would only work if one adopts a Platonist stance I guess. By immaterial I mean moreso a conscious experience. I'll add this as an edit to my question

I mean - I don't have any problems with denial of the "reality" of that abstract world, but then what "real" immaterial world did you have in mind?

like a world full of conscious experience where the objects are imagined entities and nothing else @mudskipper

If you merely consider a world of consciousness - then if this exists independently of any material world - again, why couldn't there be any laws that describe basic transformations that take one state of consciousness into another? In fact, Spinoza's Ethics could be considered as a first stab for this (and this has been used in current psychology of emotions too).

yeah I can certainly imagine those laws but what would explain the entities being distinct in that conscious experience without some sort of material substrate storing information about those distinctions?

In an imagined world imagined entities are distinct because they are imagined as distinct. It's not clear to me what you want to have explained. Whether or not there is a material substrate is totally irrelevant for this.

yes but what would be causing those particular distinctions in experience instead of another series of distinctions? WIth a material substrate storing this information, it would seem to atleast give an explanation or answer to this question. WIthout this, there seems to be no explanation

What's causing those? Tell me, what is the cause that 3 < 4? What "causes" Harry Potter to be different from Hermione? The "law" for the first is captured by the Peano axioms. What other "cause" is there except those axioms? If you want to argue for physicalism - fine - I happen to be a physicalist myself --, but that's a different issue than the question you posed.

Note that I'm not talking about what causes distinctions in an absolute manner, but distinctions in experience. The experience of a distinction is different from whether entities are in fact distinct, such as 3 and 4. Now when I experience a distinction in experience, such as a chair vs. a laptop, there is a material substrate (brain) storing this information. Without this, how would there even be abstractions of components separated by space and distinct in experience?

To put it in a different way, without a material substrate storing information pertaining to distinctions, could there be a conscious experience of a distinction between a chair and a laptop say? I suspect not but I can't find the words to justify this right now either

That's not the question you asked. So it seems both @KristianBerry and me have misunderstood what you wanted to ask. Unless you clarify the question, I don't know what to say more.

When you write "when I experience a distinction in experience, such as a chair vs. a laptop, there is a material substrate (brain) storing this information" -- that's actually going beyond mere experience. You're assuming a particular, physicalist theory here which is not a simple given. (For instance both some Greeks and the ancient Chinese believed that the heart, rather than the brain, is the seat of intelligence and the organ for processing sense information.)

that’s true but if there’s no material substrate, then how is that distinction being formed? Assuming a brain storing this information atleast explains this distinction don’t you think?

I actually agree that in some sense all our ideas derive from what our senses have let us experience and that his is intimately dependent on our bodies (and on cultural artifacts) -- but this is irrelevant for discovering laws or lawlike correlations/relations between ideas or between experiences. The question you actually want to ask seems to me whether anything apart from physicalism could be true -- which seems to me a different issue.

You seem to be asking us to draw conclusions about a thought experiment which is insufficiently defined and untestable. Mu.

A thought experiment?

I take the content of our dreams to be a good model for a solipsist universe.
As we know many physical laws from our real universe are suspended in the universe of our dreams. E.g., in our dreams we are often able to fly.
Hence some laws are valid also in the immaterial world of our dreams while others are suspended.

The understanding that dreams themselves can be induced from a fabricated source does support solipsism, however, it is important to acknowledge whether or not those dreams are actually in accord with initial source. If there is a faux initial source, as in someone has decided to manipulate the perception of actual source, then we would be seeing that which "manifests" as chaos. This chaos is nothing but a contradiction to actual order, which, actual source, requires.

Your immaterial world is by definition a hypothetical or imagined one, since the real world is not immaterial. Given that, you are free to hypothesise or imagine anything you like, including operational laws.
